# Remove cgminer package

Tags: cgminer

I would like to remove cgminer using the following command but failed to find this package. However I have multiple version installed here and need to configure that again.

```
sudo apt-get remove cgminer
```

Comment: what is your ubuntu version

Comment: Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Comment: how did you install cgminer ?

Comment: usgin weget https://github.com/ckolivas/cgminer into the folder /usr/local/src

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay execute this command in Terminal :

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/src/cgminer*
```